# Is it ok to create and place a tkinter widget at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new in Python and in tkinter so the question may seems naive: is it ok to create and place widgets at the same time if I don't need to change them? 
It works but is it a good practice? And if not why?

An example of what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(window,text='Lost Label').pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've (mostly) answered your own question when you say "if I don't need to change them"…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon @Skynet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532572/355230)....

Whenever you do `Widget(*args, **kwargs).pack()` the `pack()` method returns `None` as would other geometry managers, so if you tried to assign this to a variable the variable would be `None`.

In this case then probably not, since you probably actually want to be storing the reference to the widget.

If you don't need a reference then there's not really a problem with it. As the other answer notes you don't need a definitve reference to every single widget in your GUI unless you plan to use this reference in some way. Unless I plan on changing the label text / modifying it in someway then I typically use your method to save some space. No need to write more code than you have to!

Comment: which "previous" answer? Answers can appear in different orders at different times. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Fair point, edited. But I think the timestamps alone made it clear.

Answer (score 2):

For example you're creating a `Button` widget.

```
btn = Button(blabla, text="Button1")
```

This returns a button object and if you need later to configure it or get information about it you can do it by through the `btn` variable.
But if you use something like `btn = Button(blabla, text="Button1").pack()` it returns `None` and not a button object so you won't be able to change anything about the button or get information about it later.

Another example is with the `Entry` widget

```
entry = Entry(blabla)
```

Using that later you can do `entry.get()` to get the text inside the entry
but you won't be able to do it if you use `entry = Entry(blabla).pack()` since it doesn't return an entry object, it just packs the widget and you won't be able to access it for later use.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with that approach and I have already seen it quite a few times. You don't have to keep a reference to every widget in your GUI.